# Redis - Get total dataset size in a cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

When a Redis instance is setup and running, the dataset size (in bytes) can be retrieved from output of the below command by looking at used_memory_dataset field.

```
./redis-cli -h <ip address> -p <port> info
```

However, when I have multiple instances running in the cluster mode, how do I retrieve the dataset size across the cluster? Can redis-cli tool still be used for such cluster-based commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Redis v5 the cli includes cluster-smarts. You can use the following form to call a command, e.g. `INFO`, on all nodes:

```
redis-cli --cluster call ip:port command
```

To calculate the dataset's total size, you'd have to add up the different replies.